# How can I keep settings after flashing a ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, backup, restore, rom-flashing

I am considering flashing my SGS to a custom ROM.  I do not, however, relish the prospect of re-configuring everything.  Most apps on my phone and most definitions should have no dependencies on the ROM, so I would like to be able to back up all the settings, flash the ROM and then restore them.  This would include:

- all installed apps
- all app settings (launcher preferences, active widgets etc.)
- ringtones, backgrounds etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Titanium Backup from the Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)!

From the Technical FAQ:

1. Can it back up and restore applications across different ROMs or even different phones ?

   - YES, without restrictions.

Although you also have:

Can it back up SMS, MMS and system settings ?

- Please note that if you backup and restore all system settings across very different ROMs, you are on your own. Before restoring on a different ROM, it is strongly recommended to enable the "Data migration" option in the Titanium Backup settings.

Comment: Doesn't Titanium require you to restore to the same ROM as you backed up?

Comment: Not necessarily, from the wiki manual. Migrate system data: Use this before restoring system data from a different (incompatible) ROM, or even different phone model

Comment: I've used Titanium after flashing to a new ROM without being required to go back.  With the free version you have to manually confirm each app which is a pain, but I heard that with the paid version you can do it all at once.  Keep in mind that sometimes the ROM has a more up to date version of a particular app, depending on where you started (for instance, Samsung Galaxy S has 2.2 for MMS, keyboard, etc... whereas my custom ROM has 2.2.1 versions).

Comment: I can confirm that Titanium does not require the same ROM at all.  I'm sure in many cases it could even be done with entirely different devices.  And the paid version makes things a lot easier. It's one of the few apps I've bought and is definitely worth the money.

Comment: Just to confirm it works between different devices *and* versions, I used it to migrate from an HTC Buzz to a Motorola Droid 2. As said, just be careful with system related stuff (including SMS, call-logs, etc.), which can break things (force-close on SMS, for one). Also, the *troubleshooting options* provide additional help just-in-case.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider making a nandroid backup before anything!

Comment: Good advice, but nandroid doesn't allow settings-only restore.  This should probably be a comment?

Comment: @MatthewRead True on both counts. Wasn't sure about amending anothers post. Nandroid is a god send when your attempts at restoring settings through TB go awry. Saved my bacon!

Comment: Just a minor update - Appextractor in the Play Store does allow extracting partial data from a nandroid.