# Will flashing a custom ROM on my Galaxy Nexus device wipe my data?

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-nexus, rom-flashing

I'm wondering if I flash a custom ROM onto my Samsung Galaxy Nexus device, will it erase all my data (musics, pictures, etc.) due to its memory singularity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flashing a CustomROM (usually *any* ROM different to the one you're currently running) requires you to do a complete Wipe (well, at least it is *strongly recommended* for stability reasons) -- so the answer is probably: Yes. Data on an external SD card usually is not affected -- but as far as I remember, the GN has no such thing.

You might wish to consult the following Q&As for more information:

- [How can I keep settings after flashing a ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10652/how-can-i-keep-settings-after-flashing-a-rom?rq=1)
- [Do I need to revert to stock firmware and/or wipe data before installing a custom ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/do-i-need-to-revert-to-stock-firmware-and-or-wipe-data-before-installing-a-custo?rq=1)
- [Manually upgrade Galaxy Nexus 4.0.4 (yakjuxw) to 4.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25977/manually-upgrade-galaxy-nexus-4-0-4-yakjuxw-to-4-1?rq=1)

**EDIT:**

Just to be more clear: Data on (external|internal) SD-Card (the Nexus uses an internal eMMC *instead* of the external SD, if I'm correct) -- that is the place where you store your photos, videos, music files, etc. -- are **not** affected by the wipe. Just all "internal memory" -- i.e. the apps *you* installed, and all settings plus app data -- will be erased.

Comment: You will not lose your SD card partition with a normal wipe (on Nexus S, I have no reason to assume CWM would change that much for GNex).

It would be silly because it would nuke the backup you just made.

Comment: @Broam Nexus uses internal SD card *instead of* external, correct? So that's where you place your files (photos, videos, music...)? Then you are correct: That partition won't be affected. I will edit my answer to make that clear. Still, all user data (apps you installed, their data, etc.) are gone.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you'll need to unlock your bootloader in order to flash, and unlocking your bootloader will indeed wipe everything.

Comment: I've unlocked the bootloader which is a onetime only action. But flashing ROMs could happen many times.